# Powershell: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'

Tags: string, powershell, event-log

When I run the following code i receive the message "cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'".  How do i pass the event log list back to get-eventlog?

```
$EventLogList = Get-EventLog | Select-Object -ExpandProperty log
Get-evenlog -log $eventloglist
```

> Get-EventLog : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'LogName'.

your help is appreciated

Comment: You have a typo on the second line. It should be `eventlog` instead of `evenlog`.

Comment: And it is not clear what is your intent. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Ah right sorry. I want to retrieve all event entries from all the traditional logs. e.g. Application, HardwareEvents, Internet Explorer, Key Management Service, Security, System ect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LogName` is a mandatory parameter to `Get-EventLog` and you have to supply it, unless you are trying to do a list with `-list`. Also, it expects a string and the second line is giving the error because you are passing in an array.

Apart from that, it is also not clear what you are trying to do with the statements.

I suppose you want something like:

```
get-eventlog -list | %{ get-eventlog -log $_.log }
```

Comment: Thank you. The array was causing me the issue.  I create a foreach to loop through each of the logs individually.